# Possibility of expressing ln(x) as a sum of Hermite polynomials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, hermite-polynomials, experimental-mathematics

this might be an ill defined question, but:

I have an experiment that computes the value <n/N> (where n is a random variable and N is fixed). I'm trying to compute <log(n/N)>, which due to nonlinearity of log function is not equal to log(<n/N>). In this case $n \in [0,N]$ The distribution is assumed to be Poissonian.
Hence there arises my question:

Would it be possible to express ln(x) as a sum of Hermite polynomials on domain, let's say ($\epsilon$, $\infty$)? Or do you happen to know about any other way how to express log(x) as some sort of series (I know that Taylor is not going to work well, but maybe some other expansion would???)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does $<\cdot>$ here denote the expectation? speaking of Hermite polynomials, they form an orthonormal basis w.r.t. normal pdf only on the whole line iirc

Comment: Yes, <⋅> denotes expectation. I've read an article in wikipedia and indeed, it said that it works for ($-\infty, \infty$), but was wandering, whether there exists any construction that would make it work in this case as well.

Comment: *Hermite* has one *t*